# Design time support for Windows 8 Store app with Javascript

Tags: windows-8, winjs, blend

Does anyone know about design time support (Blend and designer in VS) for Windows 8 app with JavaScript? especially for sample data dislay in Blend.

Can I use any `winJS` helper to identify runtime vs. design time?

Thanks!

Comment: blend do support js. during initial days, I have tried blend. but now, I am more comfortable directly editing css directly. I have heard that vs non-free editions (not express) have html designer but I have not used it.

Comment: One might think that Microsoft knows about this. Did you look there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: var isInDesignMode = Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.designModeEnabled;

Answer (score 0):

I remember to have seen a specific js variable when the app was started from within blend. Something like DESIGNER or similar.